# window.onbeforeunload not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-events, onbeforeunload

I have created the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5D9qh/17/).

If you enter any input in any of the edit boxes and try to leave the page a warning is displayed which is ok.

If you enter any input and click on the button the warning is still displayed when the requirement is not to be. (I need to prevent it from displaying).

In the webpage it seems that `window.onbeforeunload` is thrown earlier than the on click event so it will always display the warning dialog even if you click the submit button.

It makes me think that the code should change to deal with the timing of the events but not sure?

Comment: What click event are you talking about? In your Fiddle nothing happens with the `window.onbeforeunload` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is to prevent the `onbeforeunload` message from showing when you submit the form.

Simply add a `submit` handler that returns the `form_has_been_modified` value to false.

```
$("#additemform").on('submit', function(e) {
    form_has_been_modified = false;
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5D9qh/21/)**

In this demo I also cleaned up your example, removing unnecessary handlers and changed `form_has_been_modified` to use the native boolean `true` and `false` instead of 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/5D9qh/17/ you can see that after entering value in the inputs and clicking submit it still displays the warning.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I'm not seeing a message when I submit the form; I'm using Chrome 28.

Comment: IE10 and Mozilla 22.0 , I have tested in CHROME and it works as expected (I am not seeing the message either).

Comment: Ah, I think I understand your problem better. When you submit the form, the message is shown, so you want to know how to prevent that. I'll update my answer.